# leading principal minor

Tags: convex-analysis

I was wondering what are the "leading principal minors" and how they differ from "other minors" and how they are calculated to be used to determine convexity and quasiconvexity of a function? I would really appreciate if someone could explain on this function:

$$f(x,y) = x^ay^b.$$

Comment: The phrase *leading principal minor* refers to matrices and the determinants of certain submatrices.  Are you using that function $f(x,y)$ to refer to entries of a matrix?

Comment: So for the above function how are those submatrices created?